# Installing Windows alongside elementary OS

Tags: release-loki, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I am fairly new to elementary OS and Ubuntu/Linux. I would like to install Windows alongside elementary OS and do a dual boot system. I have found some posts on it but they are older then two years old. I am not a computer genius either and need help with creating the partition in GParted. I found that I need to make it NTFS but my GParted wont let me chose this. I also have the Windows 10 Pro disc even though I do not have an optical drive, not sure if this is an issue. I think I can download Windows 10 Disc Image ISO File to fix the disc thing but not sure. Any help is welcome. Old post I was looking at

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu#comment29853_6321

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it, I would wipe the machine, install Windows first using the whole drive.

Then install elementary, picking the option to "install alongside Windows," then adjust the size with the slider.

If you partition now, and install Windows, Windows will overwrite the MBR, and you won't be able to boot back to elementary.

You can do that, then go in and overwrite the MBR again, but I just haven't taken the time to figure it out.

Comment: thats not something id like to do. i have a lot of data on here and would be able put it all in an external hard drive